# How to get particular fields in array of objects mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

[image]

I need only **path** in every object in the above showing figure.
I tried something like this

```
userRouter.post('/delete_products',function(req,res){
Collections.product.find({ "_id": req.body.id }, { "pimages.path": "1" },function(err,result){
    if(err)
    res.send(err)
    else
    res.send(result)
    const map=result.map(user=>user.pimages.map(user=>user.path))
    console.log(map);
})
```

})

```
[ [ '1552640783_mixer front.jpg', '1552640783_mixer back.jpg' ] ]
```

I am getting like this. I am expecting output in array of object form

```
[{'1552640783_mixer front.jpg'},{......}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Object the values are written as name : value pairs.

I didn't get the logic behind your expecting result.

Answer (score 0):

In Object the values are written as name : value pairs. 
Ex:

```
{
name : "M-DIT KOZHIKODE",
location : "Kerala",
established : 2012
}
```

I didn't get the logic behind your expecting result.